# Parallel flood fill algorithm

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, flood-fill

I have a flood fill algorithm that returns a set of uniformly coloured points in a canvas.

My implementation works just fine, but takes several seconds to compute for large canvas (>= 1000x1000):

```
def uniform_area(canvas, x, y):
    color = canvas.point(x, y).color
    stack = {(x, y)}
    visited = set()
    results = set()

    while stack:
        x1, y1 = stack.pop()
        try:
            point = canvas.point(x1, y1)
            if point.color == color:
                results.add(point)

                nearby = [
                    (x1 - 1, y1),
                    (x1 + 1, y1),
                    (x1, y1 - 1),
                    (x1, y1 + 1)
                ]

                for p2 in nearby:
                    if p2 not in visited:
                        visited.add(p2)
                        stack.add(p2)

        except PointOutOfCanvas:
            pass

    return results
```

I was looking into parallelizing it and wondering what the best solution would be.

I am not a seasoned Python developer, but I am aware of the GIL problem, so I was looking at the multiprocessing module.

Firstly I considered using a Pool of processes, but since the input is initially made of just one element and grows as new points are discovered, Pool probably doesn't quite fit the problem (please correct me if I am wrong here).

A potential solution would be to use Process, Queue and shared lists.
I implemented a first parallelized version, but it has several issues:

- It doesn't terminate for large canvas (I guess it's because every process is attempting to put some elements into a full queue leading to a deadlock).
- Processes might stop working too early because the queue is temporarily empty.
- Not sure whether this is fast at all, because of the shared visited list and the lock around it
- It looks complex and unpythonic

Here it is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Empty as EmptyQueue

class Manager:
    def __init__(self, manager, queue):
        self._visited_lock = mp.Lock()
        self._visited = manager.list()
        self._results_lock = mp.Lock()
        self._results = manager.list()
        self.queue = queue

    @property
    def results(self):
        return set(self._results)

    def visit(self, xy):
        with self._visited_lock:
            if xy not in self._visited:
                self._visited.append(xy)
                self.queue.put(xy)

    def found(self, point):
        with self._results_lock:
            self._results.append(point)


def uniform_area(canvas, x, y):
    NUM_PROCESSES = 4

    color = canvas.point(x, y).color

    manager = Manager(mp.Manager(), mp.Queue(1000))
    manager.queue.put((x, y))

    processes = [
        mp.Process(target=uniform_area_worker, args=(color, manager))
        for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES)
    ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return manager.results

def uniform_area_worker(canvas, color, manager):
    while True:
        try:
            x1, y1 = manager.queue.get_nowait()

            point = canvas.point(x1, y1)
            if point.color == color:
                manager.found(point)

                nearby = [
                    (x1 - 1, y1),
                    (x1 + 1, y1),
                    (x1, y1 - 1),
                    (x1, y1 + 1)
                ]

                for p2 in nearby:
                    manager.visit(p2)

        except PointOutOfCanvas:
            pass

        except EmptyQueue:
            break
```

I am unsure whether this is the way to go. Before I invest more time on it, I'd like to get some feedbacks.

Thanks in advance!